# Is it possible to build a WinForm app (or another type of .NET app) which allows me to interact with other windows outside the applicaiton itself?

Tags: winforms, tooltip, mouseover

I'm learning Chinese at the moment and I have gotten my hand on a Chinese dictionary definition.

Now I would like to make an interface.

All I really want the application to do is when I point my mouse pointer over any text on the screen (in any window), it would identify the text I am pointing at and then display a small form over it, which would the chinese transaction.

Is that possible to do? Can WinForms apps interact with windows outside of it's own application?

Comment: A simpler approach could be to select (highlight) the text in the other window and have your application use the Clipboard object to copy the text and then translate it.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can get text under mouse cursor by P/Invoking

- GetCursorPos
- GetClassName
- SendMessage

  - WM_GETTEXT
  - WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
- WindowFromPoint

Like mentioned [here](http://www.blackbeltvb.com/index.htm?free/classspy.htm)

[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/23/118893.aspx) is another example in C++

Answer (score 0):

A WinForms application can interact with the Windows of other applications.  Window handles exist in a global namespace so if you can get the handle of another application's window you can send it messages.  You will have to use pinvoke to do some of this, have a look at [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558(VS.85).aspx)

However, there is no standardized way to display text in a window; there are dozens of APIs for displaying text.  So when you point at text with a mouse, you can only get the pixels, but not necessarily the text.

Some window classes will allow you to send class-specific messages query for the text at a specific location, but many will not.  Your best bet is probably to use the same methods that screen readers for the blind use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader